# Doesn't the mp4 file autoplay in the browser (Chromium) provided by Burp Suite?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, burp

When I accessed the /index of the site I created, the mp4 file played.

The browser used is the browser (Chromium) provided by Burp Suite.

It played well, but strangely it is not playing now.

When accessed from the Chrome browser, the mp4 file automatically plays, but strangely, it does not play in the browser provided by Burp Suite (Chromium).

What is the reason?

I am using the Burp Suite community version and it is the latest version.

Doesn't the mp4 file autoplay in the browser (Chromium) provided by Burp Suite?

```
.....
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
    <source src="/themes/core-beta/static/img/test3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
.....
```

Once again, it played well in the browser (Chromium) provided by the original Burp Suite.

I don't know why it suddenly doesn't work.